# How to make my android app downloadable from Facebook page

Tags: android, facebook

I am making one android app and I want to post one advertisement on Facebook page that will have one video regarding my app and a link to download my android app. The user should be able to see the advertisement with video and if he wish to download my android app then after click on given link it should go to Play Store and will be able to download the app.

Anyone please help me to do this. How I can do this ?. I don't have any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give your app link on facebook , from where user can download it from there

Comment: App link i can give. But I want to show one advertisement that will have video and if user wish to download then he can download using posted link. So basically it should happen through advertisement. I mean I want to post advertisement on FB

Answer (score 1):

yes you can create your ads for your app in facebook 
please follow these guide lines
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/creating-ads
https://adespresso.com/academy/guides/facebook-ads-beginner/setting-up-your-facebook-ads-account/

Comment: Thank you so much. I will see these link. :)